# Why is Uber in Rome more expensive than a regular taxi?

Tags: taxis, rome, uber

This question was based on wrong assumption. From experience I now know that Uber is cheaper then a regular taxi. Rome2Rio is predicting the wrong prices. Can't delete this question, because it got answers, hence this disclaimer.

I have been using Uber on two occasions where I became quite a fan. Not only because of the ease of usage, but also because of the very interesting fees (cheap). When I arrived in Rome I noticed that [Rome2Rio](http://rome2rio.com) now includes Uber in their proposed routes. However, Uber seems to be more expensive then a regular taxi. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: (throwaway) Uber prices vary with expected demand; I wonder if R2R knows about this! what does the same route look like at a different time of day?

Comment: R2R often offers information that is wildly incorrect. I would not rely on it to much.

Answer (score 4):

Generally Uber taxis provide a very highly priced car like Mercedes, etc. for a cab travel. In places where the demand is high, they are able to provide at a moderate price and manage their cost. But in place where the demand and usage is less, they need to cover their costs by charging a little higher price than other cab providers.

I guess that is totally okay when you compare it with the awesome experience they provide to the people on board!

**Edit:** Please check out the Uber Rome homepage.

https://www.uber.com/cities/rome

They do not run the low end taxis and UberX here. Hence the price!!

Comment: High-end cars is the rule for taxis in Europe. But the truth is that for the most part Uber does not care so much about the costs, the drivers are stuck with those.

Comment: While now they have started UberX and UberTaxi service, the original Uber service was the UberBlack which generally provided a high end sedan.

Comment: Yes but the innovation here is providing lower-end cars as well, taxis were generally higher cars in the first place, the price of the car can't explain the difference.

Comment: +1 Good point about UberX, it still does not really explain why it would be more expensive than taxis (which does not really seem to be the case) but it might account for some of the difference with andra's earlier experience with Uber.

Comment: All the cab providers I have used, charge higher for a higher end car!

Comment: In which country? In France, Germany, the Netherlands, etc. you mostly can't get anything else and won't be charged based on the make of the car in any case (it might not even be allowed for registered cabs using an official meter). In Italy, the cars seem a bit more varied but I am not aware of special charges for high-end cars.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know in case I visit those countries. :) In India that is how it is. If you want a big car which can carry more people, you get to pay more!

Comment: That's why my first comment started with “In Europe”. Note that they can charge more for vans (carrying more people) but not for luxury (and you very often get a Mercedes anyway).

Comment: @Relaxed I never knew that! All taxis must be a luxury car in Europe as a rule? So those NY cabs couldn't work in Europe?

Comment: @verve I used “being the rule” in a slightly informal probabilistic sense. It's not a rule at all (or at least I don't know that it is), it's just generally the case. And even that generalization is not valid everywhere (cf. black cabs in London). But my point is that since prices are regulated and most taxis are already high-end sedans anyway, you can't charge more for that or hope to differentiate your service that way.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the distance and on the rates posted on uber.com, the price would seem closer to EUR 11. Uber surge pricing can make it go higher and congestions/waiting time can also impact the price (both for Uber and for regular taxis) but the rome2rio estimate seems off.